# Laravel 5.2 'Master Layout' Variable passing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

So here is what I'm trying to achieve. I have a default blade template `default.blade.php` which is extended by all of my child views.

Within my `default.blade.php` i have a foreach loop which expresses some 'global' options to the user, and example of which is below.

```
@foreach ($projects as $p)
    <li><a href='$p->project_uid'>{{ $p->project_name }}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

So to achieve this I'm having to pass the `$projects` variable via the `view('viewname', $data)` or via `View::share('projects', $projects);` in my Controller `__construct()`

Is there a better way for me to do this on a global sense so that the above calls don't need to be made?

One option i am aware of is calling a Model function from within my view, but this defies the concept of MVC so is not ideal.

Any guidance on the subject would be appreciated, Thanks.

### Edit 1

So i tried the ViewComposer solution but ran into a couple of problems.
Below is my Composer & the Service Provider Register.

**Config/app.php**

```
App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class,
```

**ComposerServiceProvider**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot() {
        // Using class based composers...
        view ()->composer ( 'default', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\MasterComposer' );
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register() {
        //
    }
}
```

**MasterComposer**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
use Sentinel;
use ProjectUsers;

class MasterComposer
{

    protected $users;

    public function __construct(ProjectUsers $users)
    {
        $uid = Sentinel::getUser()->id;
        $this->users = ProjectUsers::where("user_id", '=', $uid)->get();
    }

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('projects', $this->users);
    }
}
```

Am i missing something obvious as it doesn't seem like the Composer is being loaded at all.

### Edit 2

Fixed it myself. Realised that within the ComposerServiceProvider i need to specify a full path to my view like so.

```
view ()->composer ( 'admin/layouts/default', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\MasterComposer' );
```

Now it Works :D

Comment: Nice question-answer here,thank you for it,is there any simpler/easier way to do this ? like maybe view::make view::share ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you do this with [View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers).

> View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a
>   view is rendered. If you have data that you want to be bound to a view
>   each time that view is rendered, a view composer can help you organize
>   that logic into a single location.

Bind that data to `defualt.blade.php` view, like:

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
    $data = .... // Get data here.
    $view->with('projects', $data);
}
```

Comment: So going off the Docs' example I should register a composer via the services? I don't see the example you gave in the docs.

Comment: I think I understand though. I shall try the solution tomorrow

Comment: Yes, you should create service provider and add it to the list in `config/app.php`. Then you should create view composer. Look carefully, there is full example in docs (right after service provider example, you can use search on the page for `class ProfileComposer`).

Comment: I had a go, ran into some issue. Edited my Question